# Mongoose performance? or limitation

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a collection which has 65000 items.

When I send a query via Mongoose api like below, it works fine until it skips 24254.

```
var getLiveDoc = function(callback){
  LiveDoc.find({},{},{skip:offset, limit:9, sort:{listOrder:1}},callback);
}
```

When it reaches to 24255, it fails with foll

```
ReferenceError: /home/ubuntu/nodetest1/views/error.html:38 body is not defined at buf.push.__stack.lineno (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:242:14), <anonymous>:30:1330) at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:242:14), <anonymous>:31:23) at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:242:14), <anonymous>:31:80) at /home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:255:15 at Object.exports.render (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:293:13) at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:323:20) at View.render (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:76:8) at Function.app.render (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:504:10) at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/node_modules/express.io/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:798:7) at Object.module.exports [as handle] (/home/ubuntu/nodetest1/app.js:75:9)
```

when I run the same query in mongo console, it works fine.

any idea about this?

Comment: From the stack trace, it looks like a problem in your view.

Comment: No there is no issue on the view. Somehow it returns no result when the it skips certain items. Let's say around 25000

Answer (score 0):

If you use Express.js with Body-Parser middleware add limit parameter as the following lines;

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false, limit: '50mb' }));
```

I hope this help..